# Bitbucket pipeline mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I'm trying add mongodb on my bitbucket pipeline but I've the following error:

> Uncaught MongoError: failed to connect to server [localhost:27017] on
>   first connect

My bitbucket-pipelines.yml:

```
image: leeduc/pipelines-node-mongo

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script
          - npm install
          - npm test
          - npm run eslint
```

Any idea to solve that ?

Comment: I believe the error is because I can not access the standard port of the mongo inside the container, but I have no idea how to solve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you need a helping mongo DB service and fortunately Bitbucket now allows you to run helping services in the pipeline.  I haven't tried it but this [document](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-services-and-databases-in-bitbucket-pipelines-874786688.html) should be helpful.

Let me know if it doesn't make sense I will see if I can add an example.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run some checks before build commands, for example on Ubuntu: service mongodb status . Your task is to see if mongodb really running at that monent.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately pipelines doesn't wait for a service image to be downloaded and be up and running before start the execution of your scripts so you should manage that in your code

Answer (score 0):

I use Mongo in pipelines with Node images, I usually add Mongo as a service.

for Node:

```
image: node:13.8.0
pipelines:
  default:
   - step:
      name: Build and Test
      script: 
        - npm ci
        - npm run test
      services: # must also be defined below, in the end of the file
        - mongo # added to run the integration tests with MongoDB

  custom: # Can only be triggered manually
    deploy-to-production: 
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          script:
               …. # call script here
definitions: 
  services: 
    mongo: 
      image: mongo
```